# Spring javax.validation annotation not caught in BindingResult

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, validation, bean-validation

I am trying to add validation to my model objects (which double as my form backing beans) using javax.validation annotations.

My model looks like this:

```
public Class TestObject {
    private String myProp;
    private InnerObject innerObject;

    //getters and setters omitted
}

public Class InnerObject {
  private BigDecimal myValue;

  @NotNull
  public BigDecimal getMyValue();
}
```

In my controller I have the method call like this:

```
public View calculate(@ModelAttribute("testObject") @Valid TestObject testObject, BindingResult result)
```

I also have the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in my spring-servlet.xml file.

Everytime I run the form with a null value it tells me there are 0 binding result errors.

I am using Java 1.6 with Hibernate-Validator-4.2.0 and Validation-API-1.0.0 on my classpath.

Can anyone help me and let me know what I am doing wrong?  Been playing around with this for a while and can't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to resolve the BigDecimal error I changed:

```
private BigDecimal myField;
```

to

```
private BigDecimal myFeild = BigDecimal.Zero;
```

It works properly now.

The only downside is that since these are my form backing objects a zero is displayed in the field initially instead of a blank.

I am not sure if there is any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing your InnerObject class.  Your controller is taking a TestObject, but the field "innerObject" of the class TestObject is of type String.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the example.  I will edit to change.  Same problem though.

Comment: So what happens if you add a validated field to the TestObject instead of having it in the contained object, does that one get validated?  Something like a string with a min/max length should be easy to test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Tried that already.  Doesn't return a bindingresult either.

Comment: Hrm, I'm out of suggestions then.  Sounds like some sort of configuration problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the try.  I will keep at it and let you know if I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  getting a little further with this.  I noticed that I was still using a custom validator in my controller like this:

```
binder.setValidator(new CustomValidator());
```

So I removed it and then I added @Valid above the getter on my inner object like:

```
@Valid
public InnerObject getInnerObject();
```

Now I can see that there are binding errors in my code.  I have a new problem though.  I have @NotNull on a BigDecimal property and I get the following error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: java.math.BigDecimal
```

From the documentation it looks like BigDecimal is supported.  So not sure what is going on.  Think I am getting closer though.